# Is there a way to find which player is the host in Unity multiplayer?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm making a 2D game and I would like to connect 2 players so they can play against each other. The problem is when I connect the second player the "host" starts the game and the "client" does not because I use "NetworkServer.connections.Count" to get number of connected players and if that == 2 it should start the game and I have read some articles that the client can't access the "NetworkServer.connections.Count" it will always return 0. Now my question is if there is a way because I didn't find it to see which player is the host that created the game and which is the client, this would solve my problem emediately.

Thanks for all responses in advance.

Comment: why dont you send a message to the client https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/Networking.NetworkServer.SendToClient.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get connections to server from Client side. But! You can create SyncVar variable which will contain number of connections on Server, and if number of connections on Server changes SyncVar will update that variable on client. You will always have up-to-date info about connections. Something like this:

```
[SyncVar] public int playersConnected;
 
 void Update () 
{
     if (isServer) 
     {
        playersConnected = NetworkServer.connections.Count;
     }

     Debug.Log($"Players connected number = {playersConnected}");
}
```

Comment: If i try this code and run it on phone and in unity editor it debugs 0 all the time so it doesn't update. Should I add something else?

Comment: @AdrianLorenčič It actually should. Only if you are running it through Client and not Server. Move Debug into "if" statement and check it. For SyncVar to work it's value must be changed on server. Changing SyncVar on client doesnt do anything.